# Unable to setup development environment for Kiali

Tags: istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I want to setup developer environment for Kiali-ui. I am following [Kiali](https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui/tree/v1.48.0#quick-start) guide to do this.

But while accessing Kiali on browser(http://localhost:3000) i am getting following issue:

> Not Found

```
Cannot GET /api/auth/info
```

From console logs I am getting following issue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui/tree/v1.48.0#testing-with-kiali) link to setup proxy for the API requests:

```
  "name": "@kiali/kiali-ui",
  "version": "1.49.0",
  "proxy": "http://{IP-OF-KIALI}:20001"
```

Is there any pre-requisite to setup development environment for Kiali-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was giving wrong url of Kiali in package.json.
Following url works for me:

```
  "proxy": "http://{IP-OF-KIALI}:20001/kiali"
```

This url is of Kiali which running inside k8s pod.